# Show that the tangents at P & Q meet on the curve...

Tags: conic-sections, locus

A straight line is drawn parallel to the conjugate axis of a hyperbola $\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ to meet it and the conjugate hyperbola in the points P & Q. Show that the tangents at P & Q meet on the curve $\frac{y^4}{b^4}\left(\frac{y^2}{b^2}-\frac{x^2}{a^2}\right)=4\frac{x^2}{a^2}$.

---

So here is my approach:
taking the point P as

> $P\left(a.sec\theta, b.tan\theta \right)$,

since the line was parallel to the conjugate axis, i.e., the y axis, the x coordinate of Q will also be $(a.sec\theta)$ and by putting this in the equation of the conjugate hyperbola, I was able to get the y-coordinate of Q and finally, the point was:

> $Q\left(a.sec\theta, b\sqrt{1+sec^2\theta}\right)$

---

So finally I got the respective tangents by putting the values of P and Q in the general tangent equations:

> Tangent at P: $\frac{x.sec\theta}{a}-\frac{y.tan\theta}{b}=1$
> Tangent at Q:  $\frac{x.sec\theta}{a}-\frac{y.\sqrt{1+sec^2\theta}}{b}=-1$

---

This is where I got stuck as solving these equations yields a weird result. Can someone please let me know how I can proceed or if this approach is wrong?

Comment: (I get the same equations as you.) The solution of the system is a little cumbersome, but you're told how the coordinates should relate. So, "all you have to do" is substitute those coordinates into given locus equation and show that equality holds.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $P(a\tan u,b\sec u);Q(a\tan v,b\sec v)$

The gradient of $PQ$ is  $$\dfrac{b(\sec u-\sec v)}{a(\tan v-\tan u)}=\dfrac{b(\cos v-\cos u)}{a\sin(u-v)}=\dfrac{2b\sin\dfrac{u+v}2}{2a\cos\dfrac{u+v}2}$$

As $PQ|| $ the conjugate axis, $\cos\dfrac{u+v}2=0\implies v=(2n+1)\pi-u$ where $n$ is any integer

$\implies Q(-a\tan u,-b\sec u)$

Now form the equation of the tangents  at $P,Q$ and solve for $x,y$

Comment: @Blue, Thanks for the observation. Please find the  updated post